# Timer and exception in products

Tags: javascript

We have programmed a javascript code for a timer that we included in prestashop and it works very well. This timer is for the customer to know when his product is going to arrive. Right now, for all products it is the same date but we would like to make exceptions for certain products that would take longer to arrive. We have tried but we did not get it. Could anyone help me?.

Thank you very much!!

This is the code:

```js
function getShippingDataFromDate(curDate) {
  // 1-31
  var day = curDate.getDate();
  var deliveryDay = day;
  var nextDay = day;
  // 24h
  var hour = curDate.getHours();
  var minute = curDate.getMinutes();
  // 0-11
  var month = curDate.getMonth();
  var year = curDate.getFullYear();

  // Today is thursday
  if (curDate.getDay() == 4) {
    if (hour >= 9) {
      // move next day to wednesday (tomorrow) 9am
      nextDay += 1;
      // move delivery to monday as it gets processed on wednesday
      deliveryDay += 4;
    } else {
      // do not move next day, shows countdown until today's 9 am
      nextDay += 0;
      // move delivery to wednesday
      deliveryDay += 1;
    }
  }
  // Today is friday
  else if (curDate.getDay() == 5) {
    if (hour >= 9) {
      // move next day to monday at 9am
      nextDay += 3;
      // move delivery to tuesday as it gets processed on monday
      deliveryDay += 4;
    } else {
      // do not move next day, shows countdown until today's 9 am
      nextDay += 0;
      // move delivery to monday
      deliveryDay += 3;
    }
  }
  // Today is saturday
  else if (curDate.getDay() == 6) {
    // move next day to monday 9am
    nextDay += 2;
    // move delivery until tuesday
    deliveryDay += 3;
  }
  // Today is sunday
  else if (curDate.getDay() == 0) {
    // move next day to monday (tomorrow) 9am
    nextDay += 1;
    // move delivery until tuesday
    deliveryDay += 2;
  }
  // Any other day 
  else {
    // past 9 am, must deliver past tomorrow
    if (hour >= 9) {
      // the next day is tomorrow 9am
      nextDay += 1;
      // deliver the day past tomorrow
      deliveryDay += 2;
    }
    // before 9am, deliver tomorrow
    else {
      // do not move next day, shows countdown until today's 9 am
      nextDay += 0;
      // move delivery to tomorrow
      deliveryDay += 1;
    }
  }

  // Date to calculate the timespan until the 9:00 am of the next labour day
  // (this is the next date from now that the hour is 9:00 am).
  var nextDate = new Date(
    year,
    month,
    nextDay,
    9,
    0,
    0);

  // Estimated delivery date
  var deliveryDate = new Date(
    year,
    month,
    deliveryDay,
    9,
    0,
    0
  );

  var result = {
    curDate: curDate,
    nextDate: nextDate,
    deliveryDate: deliveryDate,
  };

  shippingAdjustHolidays(result, year, month, day, hour, minute, deliveryDay, nextDay);

  return result;
}

function shippingAdjustHolidays(shippingData, year, month, day, hour, minute, deliveryDay, nextDay) {
  /** Exception for holidays **/

  // Fecha de entrega
  var deliveryDate = shippingData.deliveryDate;
  // Fecha para el "pídalo antes de ...."
  var nextDate = shippingData.nextDate;
  var altered = false;

  // Antes del momento límite nos aseguramos que se anuncia la entrega en el siguiente
  // día
  // Month is 0-based, 2 is march
  if (month == 11 && day == 31 && hour <= 9) {
    altered = true;
    deliveryDate = new Date(
      year,
      0, // Month is 0-based, 2 is march
      3,
      9,
      0,
      0
    );
  }
  // Tras el momento límite hay que mostrar la fecha fija hasta el último día laborable 
  // antes del primer día normal ya que sabados y domingos ya están manejados correctamente.
  // Month is 0-based, 2 is march
  else if (((month == 11 && day == 31 && hour > 9) || (month == 11 && day > 31)) && (month == 11 && day <= 25)) {
    altered = true;
    deliveryDate = new Date(
      year,
      0, // Month is 0-based, 2 is march
      3,
      9,
      0,
      0
    );

    nextDate = new Date(
      year,
      0, // Month is 0-based, 2 is march
      3,
      9,
      0,
      0);
  }

  /** Exception for poming only applies if no special date is set **/

  if (window.id_product && window.id_product == 49) {
    deliveryDate = new Date(
      year,
      month,
      deliveryDay + 5,
      9,
      0,
      0
    );

    nextDate = new Date(
      year,
      month,
      nextDay,
      9,
      0,
      0);

    /** Everything else **/
  }

  // Check if the previous correction caused the days to drift and move into non-business
  // days.
  var fixedIt = false;

  // If the next date is saturday or sunday move it to monday
  if (deliveryDate.getDay() == 6) {
    // If the next day is saturday must wait two additional days
    deliveryDay = deliveryDate.getDate() + 2;
    fixedIt = true;
  } else if (deliveryDate.getDay() == 0) {
    // If the next day is sunday must wait one additional day
    deliveryDay = deliveryDate.getDate() + 1;
    fixedIt = true;
  }

  if (fixedIt) {
    deliveryDate = new Date(
      deliveryDate.getYear(),
      deliveryDate.getMonth(),
      deliveryDay,
      9,
      0,
      0
    );
  }

  fixedIt = false;

  if (nextDate.getDay() == 6) {
    // If the next day is saturday must wait two additional days
    nextDay = nextDate.getDate() + 2;
    fixedIt = true;
  } else if (nextDate.getDay() == 0) {
    // If the next day is sunday must wait one additional day
    nextDay = nextDate.getDate() + 1;
    fixedIt = true;
  }

  if (fixedIt) {
    nextDate = new Date(
      nextDate.getYear(),
      nextDate.getMonth(),
      nextDay,
      9,
      0,
      0
    );
  }

  shippingData.deliveryDate = deliveryDate;
  shippingData.nextDate = nextDate;
}

function shippingDateToString(jDate) {
  var dayNames = ["sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday"];

  var str = "" + jDate.getFullYear() +
    "/" + (jDate.getMonth() + 1) +
    "/" + jDate.getDate() +
    " (" + dayNames[jDate.getDay()] + ")" +
    " " + jDate.getHours() +
    ":" + jDate.getMinutes() +
    ":" + jDate.getSeconds();

  return str;
}

function logShippingData(data) {
  console.log(
    "shippingData {\n\tcurDate: " + shippingDateToString(data.curDate) +
    ", \n\tnextDate: " + shippingDateToString(data.nextDate) +
    ", \n\tdeliveryDate: " + shippingDateToString(data.deliveryDate) + "}");
}

function updateShippingHoursLeft(hoursTpl, strings, disabled, curDate, updateDisplay) {

  if (disabled) {
    jQuery('#estimated_delivery_date').css("display", "none");
    return;
  }

  updateDisplay = (typeof updateDisplay == "undefined") ?
    true :
    updateDisplay;

  curDate = curDate || new Date();

  var deliveryData = getShippingDataFromDate(curDate);

  var nextDate = deliveryData.nextDate;
  var deliveryDate = deliveryData.deliveryDate;
  var curDate = deliveryData.curDate;

  var timeLeftMillis = nextDate - curDate;

  var days = Math.floor(
    timeLeftMillis /
    (1000 * 3600 * 24));

  timeLeftMillis -= days * 24 * 3600 * 1000;

  var hours = Math.floor(
    timeLeftMillis /
    (1000 * 3600));

  timeLeftMillis -= hours * 3600 * 1000;

  var minutes = Math.floor(
    timeLeftMillis /
    (1000 * 60));

  timeLeftMillis -= minutes * 60 * 1000;

  var seconds = Math.floor(
    timeLeftMillis /
    (1000));

  var dateStr = hoursTpl
    .replace("[DATE_DAY]", '<span class="time-units">' + deliveryDate.getDate() + '</span>')
    .replace("[DATE_DAY_OF_WEEK]", '<span class="time-units">' + strings.weekDays[deliveryDate.getDay()] + '</span>')
    .replace("[DATE_MONTH]", '<span class="time-units">' + (deliveryDate.getMonth() + 1) + '</span>')
    .replace("[DATE_MONTH_NAME]", '<span class="time-units">' + (strings.months[deliveryDate.getMonth()]) + '</span>')
    .replace("[DATE_YEAR]", '<span class="date-units">' + deliveryDate.getFullYear() + '</span>')
    .replace("[DAYS]", days)
    .replace("[HOURS]", hours)
    .replace("[MINUTES]", minutes)
    .replace("[SECONDS]", seconds);

  if (days > 0) {
    dateStr = dateStr
      .replace("[DATE_DAYS_LEFT]", '<span class="time-units">' + days + '</span> d&iacute;as ');
  } else {
    dateStr = dateStr
      .replace("[DATE_DAYS_LEFT]", '');
  }

  if (updateDisplay) {
    jQuery('#estimated_delivery_date').html(dateStr);
    jQuery('#estimated_delivery_date').css("display", "inline");
  } else {
    return dateStr;
  }
}
```

Edited!

Good! Thanks for answering.

This code was done by another programmer and I'm a bit of a rookie with it: P

There is a line that says:

```
/** Exception for poming only applies if no special date is set **/

  if (window.id_product && window.id_product == 49) {
deliveryDate = new Date(
  year,
  month,
  deliveryDay + 5,
  9,
  0,
  0
);

nextDate = new Date(
  year,
  month,
  nextDay,
  9,
  0,
  0);

/** Everything else **/
  }
```

This should make reference to what I say, right? I have tried to change the values but there is no difference in the results.

Thank you!!

Comment: _"We have tried but we did not get it"_ isn't a great problem description for the amount of code you've posted.  What have you tried, and what happened?

Comment: Hi James Thorpe, I have edited the post and added details about the specific code. Thank you very much for answering.

Comment: Does anyone know anything? :/